# Flutter App Crash since Flutter / Android Studio Update

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I upgraded Android Studio to 3.3.0 and Flutter to 1.0.0.

The first thing that happened, was all the packages were highlighted as missing, and I upgraded all the versions to the latest versions

Packages:

```
**Pubspec.yaml**

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
url_launcher: 3.0.2 > updated to 5.0.0
firebase_admob: 0.5.5 > updated to 0.8.0
path_provider: 0.4.1 > updated to 0.5.0
flutter_html: 0.7.0 > updated to 0.9.3
geolocator: 1.7.0 > updated to 2.1.1
sqflite: ^1.1.0 
http: ^0.12.0+1 > this was added cos it started showing as missing since the update.
```

I then updated to the latest versions for the other files

```
**In /android/build.gradle**
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

**In /android/build.gradle**
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

**In /android/app/build.gradle**
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}
```

With the changes made, I ran the app in the emulator and it immedietly crashed with no error messages

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Application finished.
```

I then tried reverting all the versions, including the packages in pubspec.yaml back to the previous ones.

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4
gradle-4.4-all.zip
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

This still crashed the app instantly on running.

At this point, I deleted the virtual devices and created new ones, and I also tried running it on my own phone plugged in. Same result - the app crashes instantly.

As a last resort, I completely removed all the packages and re-made the main.dart page to a simple page that doesn't use any packages - and even this crashes instantly.

However, if I created a new Flutter app, it is able to run.

What am I missing? Is there somewhere else that I need to change the version to the older one that I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

I compared file-by-file a new flutter app with mine, and finally realised the entire kotlin directory was missing from android/app/src/main/kotlin
I copied over the directory from an earlier version, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

An other case could be that your device was too old to support the AndroidX environment (api >= 28).
androidX support is needed to include path_provider (perhaps firebase_admob too)

Personnally, I replace the call to path_provider (getApplicationDocumentsDirectory) with sqflite (getDatabasesPath) and I remove path_provider. My app is running good on Marshmallow without path_provider.